# Facebook share to one friend only

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I am trying to build a functionality where a notification can be send by the user from my application to one other friend from his friend list. I tried to implement this with a [request](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/send-requests?locale=nl_NL), but the picker allows the selection of multiple friends.

I know I can get a list of all the friends of the user, but I do not know hot to send a notification to a single friend the user selects.

So I was wondering if there is a way to either limit the requestdialog to  select a single friend or to send a notification to a specific friend.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is an acceptable way to share your content, but you may want to try just sending a message. The latest API has support for [Message Dialogs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/share?locale=en_PI#message-dialog)

I hope this is helpful in answering your question, but I understand that it may not be.

Happy coding! I hope this helps, leave a comment if there's anything I can help you with.

Comment: I read about the message dialogs, but those will show up in the messages of the friend instead in the notification list. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Oh, I better understand the problem. I'll put my thinking cap on.

Comment: I tried to use the message dialog, but I don't know how to restrict the message to only one friend